# How can I graph results from common data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm not entirely sure how to word this question for the title, but I can give a simplified example to (hopefully) explain my issue better. Say I have the following tables:

Maths Class:

| Student | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 90 |
| Alex | 75 |
| Bob | 85 |
| Jake | 80 |
| Jake | 95 |
| Steve | 60 |

Science Class:

| Student | Score |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | 95 |
| Ash | 80 |
| Bob | 90 |
| Bob | 75 |
| Steve | 85 |

and

| Student | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Alex | Senior |
| Ash | Sophomore |
| Bob | Freshman |
| Jake | Senior |
| Steve | Junior |

This image below shows the desired format of the graph, but was created by having scores & grade levels in the same table. Ideally I wouldn't have to do that. This is a simplified example, but to do that for my real data would mean adding to half a dozen graphs.

Additionally, not every student took every test, and some students took a test multiple times and have several scores.

I understand how to handle this, and I'm fine with the graph including several scores from the same student. Just mentioning it because I'd prefer to keep separate tables for each subject. I feel that combining all of the subjects onto one table would result in a muddle of students and scores that would be hard to understand at first glance.

Is it possible for excel to do this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could use power query to join the data [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6fPf.png) which would give you a table like this [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34naZ.png) and base you charts off that.

Comment: @BlindSpots I've updated my post - does that clarify your questions?

Comment: Looks good.  Left a comment showing how to merge the data so you can filter by grade for your chart.